Cross product properties.
I just want to know if it's correct: let $\vec{v}=(\vec{a}+\alpha\vec{b})\times(2\vec{a}+\vec{b})$, with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.
If $||\vec{a}||=\sqrt{2},||\vec{b}||=1$ and the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is $\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$, for which values of $\alpha$, $||\vec{v}||=1$?
Using cross product properties,
$$\vec{v}  =\vec{a}\times 2\vec{a}+\vec{a}\times\vec{b}+\alpha\vec{b}\times 2\vec{a}+\alpha\vec{b}\times\vec{b}$$
$$\vec{v}  =\vec{0}+\vec{a}\times\vec{b}+2\alpha(-\vec{a}\times\vec{b})+\alpha\cdot\vec{0}$$
$$\vec{v}  =(1-2\alpha)\vec{a}\cdot(\times\vec{b})$$
Therefore,
$$||\vec{v}||=|1-2\alpha|\cdot||\vec{a}\times\vec{b}||$$
and then,
$$1  = |1-2\alpha|\cdot||\vec{a}||\cdot||\vec{b}||\cdot\sin\theta $$
$$1 = |1-2\alpha|\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot1\cdot\sin\dfrac{3\pi}{4} $$
$$1  = |1-2\alpha|$$
Hence,
$$\alpha=0\qquad\text{or}\qquad\alpha=1$$

This is correct.
